# How do I make a azure function RESTful crud operation and powershell

Tags: azure-functions, powershell-7.0

I'm trying to create my first azure function using powershell. I want to make a restful crud set of functions, but it seems to only allow one function to be routed. Is there a way to add different routes to the methods in function.json?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform crud operations in 2 methods:

> Method - 1

1. For Creating Power shell Functions all you need is to create local project from Visual studio.
2. Run the function locally by running the current project on your local development computer before you publish to Azure.
3. Sign in to your Azure Account or If you aren't already signed in, choose the Azure icon in the Activity bar, then in the **Azure: Functions** area, choose **Sign in to Azure**.
4. When prompted in the browser, choose your Azure account and sign in using your Azure account credentials.
5. After you've successfully signed in, you can close the new browser window. The subscriptions that belong to your Azure account are displayed in the Side bar.
6. Publish the project to Azure.
7. Now Run the Functions in Azure.

For more information Please refer the Attached link : [PowershellAzureFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-powershell?WT.mc_id=docs-azuredevtips-azureappsdev)

> Method - 2

```
## Initializing the module

$storage = "addYourStorageNameHere"

$key = "addYourStorageSecretKeyHere"

Import-Module AZTableModule.psm1 -ArgumentList $storage, $key

## Creating a new table

New-AzTable "sampletable"

## Add a new entry to your table

# - Dates must be older or equal than "1901-01-01"

# - Replaces the entry if the unique key and partitionkey matches

$birthDate = (Get-date -date "1983-01-02")

$patrick = @{

PartitionKey = 'yourPartitionName'

RowKey = 'yourUniqueRowKeyPatrick'

"birthDate@odata.type"="Edm.DateTime"

birthDate = $birthDate.toString("yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00.000Z")

name = "Patrick"

lastname = "Lamber"

}

Add-AzTableEntry -table "sampletable" -partitionKey $patrick.PartitionKey -rowKey $patrick.RowKey -entity $patrick

## Create a new entry or merge it with an existing one

$birthDate = (Get-date -date "1986-10-19")

$rene = @{

PartitionKey = 'yourPartitionName'

RowKey = 'yourUniqueRowKeyRene'

"birthDate@odata.type"="Edm.DateTime"

birthDate = $birthDate.toString("yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00.000Z")

name = "Rene'"

lastname = "Lamber"

}

Merge-AzTableEntry -table "sampletable" -partitionKey $rene.PartitionKey -rowKey $rene.RowKey -entity $rene

## Return a single entry

$patrickFromTheCloud = Get-AzTableEntry -table "sampletable" -partitionKey $patrick.PartitionKey -rowKey $patrick.RowKey

## Update an individual field of an existing entry

$patrickFromTheCloud = Get-AzTableEntry -table "sampletable" -partitionKey $patrick.PartitionKey -rowKey $patrick.RowKey

$patrickFromTheCloud.name = "Patrick has been updated"

Merge-AzTableEntry -table "sampletable" -partitionKey $patrickFromTheCloud.PartitionKey -rowKey $patrickFromTheCloud.RowKey -entity $patrickFromTheCloud

## Get all entries

$entries = Get-AzTableEntries -table "sampletable"

## Select individual fields from the table

$entriesWithSomeProperties = Get-AzTableEntries -table "sampletable" -select "RowKey,PartitionKey,name"

## Filter entries

$filteredEntries = Get-AzTableEntries -table "sampletable" -filter "name eq 'Patrick'"

## Delete an entry

Remove-AzTableEntry -table "sampletable" -partitionKey $rene.PartitionKey -rowKey $rene.RowKey

## Delete a table

Remove-AzTable -table "sampletable"
```

For more details,refer [attached link](https://www.nubo.eu/azure-table-storage-crud-operations-with-Powershell/)

Comment: Thanks @Swethakandikonda-MT. I was really trying to figure out how to create multiple functions with the same name responding to different HTTP verbs. The azure function project only allows one file per binding.

Comment: @kevin sure we can do that, you can use `Push-OutputBinding` to send multiple data to output bindings in PowerShell. you can refer [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal) for more detailed Information